# C# MongoDB query on date range

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

I'm new to C# MongoDB driver, and have a question regarding querying objects with date range.
Here is my collection

```
[
{"ssimTmi":"L","ssimCcd":"AA","ssimSp1":" ","ssimFlt":" 000","ssimIvn":"8 ","ssimLsn":"  ","ssimStc":" ","ssimPop":"05JAN1800XXX00","ssimBeg":"05JAN18","ssimDay":"05","ssimMon":"JAN","ssimYyr":"18","ssimEnd":"00XXX00","ssimDop":"05JAN18","ssimFri":"O","ssimLdd":"AG SSIM PRODUCT   ","ssimDsc":"AG "},

{"ssimTmi":" ","ssimCcd":"AA","ssimSp1":" ","ssimFlt":" 001","ssimIvn":"01","ssimLsn":"01","ssimStc":"J","ssimPop":"07JUN1807JUN18","ssimBeg":"07JUN18","ssimDay":"07","ssimMon":"JUN","ssimYyr":"18","ssimEnd":"07JUN18","ssimDop":"123456 ","ssimFri":" ","ssimLdd":"JFK08000800-05008 ","ssimDsc":"JFK"},

{"ssimTmi":" ","ssimCcd":"CO","ssimSp1":" ","ssimFlt":" 001","ssimIvn":"01","ssimLsn":"01","ssimStc":"J","ssimPop":"09NOV1809NOV18","ssimBeg":"09NOV18","ssimDay":"09","ssimMon":"NOV","ssimYyr":"18","ssimEnd":"09NOV18","ssimDop":"123456 ","ssimFri":" ","ssimLdd":"JFK08000800-05008 ","ssimDsc":"JFK"}
]
```

I want to write a query to get "ssimDsc" when we give the Date as input. If i give date as 03MAR18...It should return the collection for all the entries where "ssimBeg" falls on 03MAR18 and after 03MAR18...It should not show JAN and FEB data..

Could you please help in acheiving this.

Comment: You can't do $gte and $lt queries on dates stored as strings. Any reason why you didn't use ISODate or ticks?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is the recommended way, but if you can run javascript on the server side, you can construct a `BsonDocument` containing a javascript query.

For example, the following piece of code assumes that a `System.DateTime targetDate` is provided on a collection called "ssi":

```
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ssi");
string javaScript = "function(){ ";
javaScript += "mlist = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']; ";
javaScript += "month = mlist.indexOf(this.ssimMon); day = parseInt(this.ssimDay); year = parseInt(this.ssimYyr) + 2000; ";
javaScript += "dateItem = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day)); ";
javaScript += $"targetDate = new Date(Date.UTC({targetDate.Year}, {targetDate.Month}, {targetDate.Day})); ";
javaScript += "return dateItem > targetDate; }";
BsonJavaScript bScript = new BsonJavaScript(javaScript);
BsonDocument query = new BsonDocument("$where", bScript);

var result = collection.Find(query).ToList();
```

If the server side does not accept java-script you can handle it by traversing over de complete result set, but that is not desirable.

I hope this helps.